# ZooKeeper alternative for .net

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is there any alternative of ZooKeeper in .net? Other than database which we all use for similar stuff.

We need it for leader selection and to make sure one item is getting processed only once and various distributed status sharing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why do you want a .NET version of ZooKeeper? As long as you don't intend to hack ZooKeeper itself you could just install it and use it.
If you're searching for a .NET client for ZooKeeper, this may help you: http://erichauser.net/2010/04/23/zookeeper-net-client/
There's also an improved REST interface for ZooKeeper underway: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-809

Comment: REST support would be great, problem with .net clients with opensource products are they fall behind and often left alone in dust. As product like ZooKeeper become heart of your application it is much better to go with fully supported product. But REST would solve that problem.

Comment: Well, why don't you help then to maintain the .net client? It's free software (unlike .net) so you're free to help out.

Comment: @Thomas Koch. No part of .NET costs money and Mono is an implementation that works on Linux.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.
Accepted answer should be actually an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZooKeeperNetEx/

A .NET async Client fully compliant with ZooKeeper, supporting all features. Fully Task-based Asynchronous (async/await).